# Shortening my code

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm trying to push out a questionnaire at work with several questions on. Users can reply with radio buttons ranging from yes, some, maybe and no. This questionnaire is contained in the sheet called manager.

If they select yes or no I would like to copy the question to a seperate sheet in a table labelled yes and no with whether they selected yes or no. This sheet is called Follow Up.

I have over 200 questions so you can understand why I'd like to shorten the code please.

My secondary problem is if they change their mind from no to yes i'd like to delete the copied question from the no column. As it stands as they change their mind the question gets copied into both.

The following is the code i already have:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then 'This is yes
    Worksheets("Manager").Range("B3").Copy _ 'Within B3 is the person's name
    Destination:=Worksheets("Follow Up").Range("B3") 'In this B3 I need the person's name
End If

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("Manager").Range("B9").Copy _ 'B9 holds the question
    Destination:=Worksheets("Follow Up").Range("B6") 'B6 is where I want it to go
End If
End Sub


Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()

If OptionButton4.Value = True Then 'This is for no
    Worksheets("Manager").Range("B3").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Follow Up").Range("B3")
End If

If OptionButton4.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("Manager").Range("B9").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Follow Up").Range("C6")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If this code works for you but you want to improve it, then this question may be more appropriate on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: What if someone changes their mind on a question?  Your "no" procedure needs to undo your "Yes" and vice-versa.

Comment: That's the bit I'm stuck on Tim

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, but it's difficult to provide a really useful answer without knowing how your other questions are structured.

The code below still relies on hard-coding the ranges (B3,B6,C6, etc) for a given question: but if your questions are all structured the same then it should be possible to add one more parameter to `TheAnswer` so it knows which cells it should operate on.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    TheAnswer OptionButton1.Value = True 'Yes-->True
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
    TheAnswer Not OptionButton4.Value = True 'No --> False
End Sub

Private Sub TheAnswer(IsYes As Boolean)

    Dim shtM As Worksheet, shtF As Worksheet
    Set shtM = Worksheets("Manager")
    Set shtF = Worksheets("Follow Up")

    shtF.Range("B3").Value = shtM.Range("B3").Value
    shtF.Range("B6:C6").ClearContents
    shtF.Cells(6, IIf(IsYes, 2, 3)).Value = shtM.Range("B9").Value

End Sub
```